# Select slices from tensor A based on tensor B in TensorFlow while both having dynamic batch size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a tensor `params` of shape `(None, 100, 10)` and a Boolean tensor `indices` of shape `(None, 100)`. Note that the `None` is due to the dynamic batch size. I would like to create a tensor `c` that will have shape `(None, None, 10)` and gathers slices from `params` where `indices` is `True` (or `1`). The suggested solutions on stackoverflow use `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd`. But they do not work as detailed below.

I tried the followings and they did not work:

1. `tf.gather(params, indices)` but it gives me a wrong result with shape `(None, 100, 100, 10)`
2. `params[indices]` but it gives me a wrong result with shape `(None, 10)`
3. `tf.gather(params, indices)` which raises a ValueError saying `ValueError: indices.shape[-1] must be <= params.rank, but saw indices shape: [?,100] and params shape: [?,100,10]`. Fixing it by expanding the `indices` dimension (`indices = tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=-1)`) and then `tf.gather(params, indices)` gives wrong shape of `(none, 100, 100, 10)`.

Comment: For gather you need to pass coordinates as inputs not 1s/0s. And for batch you need to set batch_dim=1. But here I see for each batch, the indices will need to gather different lengths, so you will have a RaggedTensor, that's what you want to create?.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vijayachandranmariappan. Both of your comments are correct. The way I used `tf.gather` was not correct. Also, yes the expected result would be a ragged tensor.